# Why is this for loop doubling the size of my ArrayList?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

This is a homework assignment.

I am prompting the user to input any amount of numbers, followed by a word. Because I do not know the amount of numbers that will be input, I am storing them in a String[], then moving them to an ArrayList.
I am storing the input correctly into the String[] by splitting the scanner input at white spaces.

Now I am attempting to add the contents of a String[] into an ArrayList with the following:

```
    int i = 0;

    for ( i = 0; i < inputToStringArray.length; i++) { 
        if(values.add(Double.parseDouble(inputToStringArray[i]))){  //if you can parse a double, parse a double
            values.add(Double.parseDouble(inputToStringArray[i]));
        }
    }
```

Because I do not want the word at the end of the input, I am parsing the String[] for doubles.
Problem is, the ArrayList copies each number, storing it twice consecutively.
An input of 1, 2.2, 3.3 will store as 1.0, 1.0, 2.2, 2.2, 3.3, 3.3.

Why?

Comment: Because this is what you put in your code. you have `values.add` **twice**.

Comment: "My code has no bugs, it runs exactly the way I wrote it"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically, if `List#add` returns `true`, you're adding it again...

```
if(values.add(Double.parseDouble(inputToStringArray[i]))){  //if you can parse a double, parse a double
    values.add(Double.parseDouble(inputToStringArray[i]));
}
```

Which basically says...

```
if add(value) { 
    add(value) // again...
}
```

Something like...

```
for ( i = 0; i < inputToStringArray.length; i++) { 
    try {
        values.add(Double.parseDouble(inputToStringArray[i]));
    } catch (NumberFormatException exp) {
        System.err.println(inputToStringArray[i] + " is not a valid double");
    }
}
```

May work better...

Comment: List.add *always* returns true.

Comment: I see my error. Thank you very much! Will cite this answer in my hw.

Comment: @DavidEhrmann I was discussing more about the state of the `if` statement then the requirements of `List` and this context your comment is true, but if the `List` implementation is unknown, it's possible it could return `false` if the `List` implementation couldn't add the element for some reason...just saying...

Comment: No, [List.add()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add(E)) returns true. If it doesn't, someone's doing something *very* wrong. If it returns false, it won't mean anything because it's an undefined behavior.

Comment: @DavidEhrmann It's not undefined, `Collections#add` clear defines it.  *"Return: true if this collection changed as a result of the call"* - which means if it returns `false` the `List` was not changed as a result of call, which suggests that the item could not be added, but that's implementation details - `ArrayList` will always return `true`, it's coded that way, or throw an `OutOfMemoryException` because it couldn't resize it's internal cache...;)

Comment: @DavidEhrmann Add in the context of the this question it's some what mute, because the OP shouldn't have been relying on the result to determine if the conversion worked ;)

Answer (score 1):

Because you are adding it twice! Your `If` statement is attempting to add it to `values`, then if it succeeds, you are adding it again.

Try something like this:

```
int i = 0;

for ( i = 0; i < inputToStringArray.length; i++) { 
    try {
        values.add(Double.parseDouble(inputToStringArray[i]));
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        // not a number!
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

a) In fact you call the method values.add() twice (you don't need it on the if clause).

b) You may encounter an exception if the string value is not a number, you should catch this

You should use something like this:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < inputToStringArray.length; i++) {
    try {
        values.add(Double.parseDouble(inputToStringArray[i]));   
    } catch (NumberFormatException e){} 
}
```